# How to set vlc to be the default player for .avi files

Tags: vlc, default-programs

I'm using ubuntu 15.04. I installed VLC and want it to be the default player for all video files including .avi files. I tried all the recommended methods but nothing works.
Here is what I already tried:

1. Went to System Settings/ System info/ Default Applications and set VLC as default for video. VLC is now set as default video player but double clicking on an .avi file still opens it with SMPlayer.
2. Right clicking the avi file, then Properties, and then Open With and click on VLC to change the default program. Does not work - SMPplayer remains set the default application.
3. Used Ubuntu Tweak / admin tab / system / File type manager / Video category, double click on the line 'AVI vide' and select VCL media player. Does not work - SMPlayer remains the default application.
4. Edited the file /usr/share/applications/defaults.list and changed all occurrences of totem.desktop to vlc.desktop. Does not work.

I logged out and in again after each of these methods.

Now I'm out of ideas, what else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** **Choice number one: Open a terminal where your file is and do the folloing command**

```
mimeopen -d your_video.avi
```

there is the output:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type application/x-ms-dos-executable
    1) vlc
    2) ...
    3) Other...
use application #3
use command: vlc %f
```

Press 1 if you see vlc, if not, chose the Other solution (3 in that case)
Then type the name of your application followed by %f.

**2. Choise 2:**

```
mimeopen .avi
```

and then do the step above.